# Вывод массива в шаблон через переменную

Tags: php, html

```
   while ($row1 = $result1->fetchObject()) {
    #тут переменные
            if ($pass == $adminpass) {
                $delnew = "<a onclick='send(&apos;$nid&apos;);' href='#Сообщение'>Удалить</a> || ";
            }
            echo "
        <div class='container'>
                       <div class='title'><a id='t' href='/?new=$nid'>$title</a><span style='color:gray;float:right;'>$date</span></div>
                       <div id='box-news'>
                       <span>$textn</span>
                       <br><br><span style='font-size:10pt;font-weight: bold;'>Добавил: <b>$admin</b><span style='float:right'>$delnew<a href='/?new=$nid'>Подробнее</a></span></span>
                       </div>
                    </div>
        ";
        }
```

И я хочу вывести все что выводит массив в переменную $main_content:

```
<div class=main-container>
$main_content
</div>
```

Как мне это сделать? Если поменять echo на значение переменной выводиться только одна новость.

Comment: вместо echo внутри while например `$output .= ... `,затем `<div class=main-container>echo $output</div>`.

Comment: Я ж в конце написал, выводится последняя новость если их несколько, они же все будут делать $output = ... А html код у меня тоже в echo находиться.

Comment: Смотрите внимательнее, я написал `.=`, что значит конкатекацию строк.

Comment: Можете ещё ответить на вопрос: как сделать редирект .htaccess с главной страницы на /?engine=news. По сути то и то и то является главной страницей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переношу в ответ, вместо echo внутри while например

```
$output .= 'ваш html-код'; //конкатекация
```

затем в шаблоне

```
 <div class=main-container>
   <?php echo $output; ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Замена `$main_content= '';` на `$main_content .= '';` помогла, спасибо.